# PBE: (Tutorial2) Problem with spatialManager variable

Tags: actionscript-3

I've just started with PBE. Now trying to follow few first tutorials. Have problem with the second one(http://pushbuttonengine.com/docs/Lesson-02.html). E.g. this line of code: 
spatial.spatialManager = PBE.spatialManager;

throws the:
Attempted access of inaccessible property spatialManager through a reference with static type Class.

Could you please help me. these are my first steps with PBE...a bit hard :(

Comment: I didn't have a problem with it and I just tried out all five lessons (using Flex Builder 3). But I would make sure that you imported com.pblabs.engine.PBE. If that's not the problem, I suggest (1) trying to see if the provided zip file works/compiles for you, or (2) write the ActionScript Project from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was with incorrect version of lib I've used. After PBE update (to 1.0) it worked